# Eigenvalues for orthogonal matrix of even/uneven dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an square orthogonal matrix with real entries. Suppose the
>   size of $A$ is even and $det(A)=-1$. Show $\lambda=1$ is an
>   eigenvalue for $A$.
>
> Next suppose $A$ is of uneven size and $det(A)=1$. Show $\lambda=1$ is an
>   eigenvalue for $A$.

I'm having trouble with the following problem. I'm thinking I somehow might use the fact that $det(-A)=det(A)$ for a matrix of even size and $det(-A)=-det(A)$ for a matrix of uneven size, but I couldn't figure anything out. Any hints is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1) The eigenvalues of a (real, to be sure) orthogonal matrix are $\;\pm1\;$ .

2) The determinant of **any** square matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.